# Accordion immediately collapses after state change

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-accordion

I'm working with Bootstrap's Accordion in a React app. Each Accordion item has a form in its body. It seems straightforward except the Accordion immediately closes whenever any character is entered in a field (onChange triggered). After trial and error, I believe the issue could be related to useState. The Accordion doesn't close if I don't do a state change.

I can reproduce the issue in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-feather-jp1lbb?file=/src/App.js).

I can't figure out why this is happening. If anyone has any suggestions, I much appreciate it.

Thank you!

Comment: `key={randomId(5)}` You're using random keys. When the key changes, the component unmounts/remounts. What are these keys supposed to do?

Comment: Wow, what a simple fix - removing the random keys did the trick!
The keys are cruft, but I figured they were harmless. Ooops. 
Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 0):

Removing the randomId() call in the 'key' prop fixed the issue. Thank you for the assistance!